# After hitting breakpoint in pytest using PyCharm, it doesn't show variables and can't resume

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, pytest, breakpoints

It's hard to describe the issue without sharing the entire codebase but I'll do my best. I'm using a big QA project that is organized with pytest. I try to debug it in PyCharm.

```
class TestDownloadHistoricalRaw(base_test.BaseTest):
    @classmethod
    def callme(cls):
        logger.info("INFO: Download Raw data!")
        print("==debug== 1")
        print("==debug== 2")  # breakpoint
        print("==debug== 3")  # breakpoint
    ...
    ...
```

I set breakpoints at the `==debug== 2` and `==debug== 3` lines. Then I ran pytest on class `TestDownloadHistoricalRaw`.
[image]

PyCharm correctly executes the program and pauses at the `==debug== 2` line. But it has trouble showing variables. And `Evaluation` doesn't work for any expressions at all. 
[image]

When I click `Step Over`, the program hangs there without any progression. It can't reach `==debug== 3`.

I tried to add breakpoints to a hello world program wrapped in a pytest class. I can set breakpoints and see variables all fine. So now I'm stuck and not sure what to do.

Comment: pytest does a bunch of AST rewriting. The code that actually runs doesn't look like what you see, or what PyCharm expects. That may be part of the problem.

Comment: Generally, debugging pytest works in PyCharm. It could be that one of your fixtures or setup code interferes with the test runner, for example if you do something like reloading / unloading modules. Pytest does a lot of stuff under the hood that can interfere with that.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cov/issues/131